# Why is Docker installed but not Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have installed docker on CentOS 7 by running following commands,

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
systemctl enable docker && systemctl start docker
docker run hello-world
```

**NOTE: helloworld runs correctly and no issues.**

however when I try to run `docker-compose` (docker-compose.yml exists and valid) it gives me the error on CentOS only (Windows version works fine for the docker-compose file)

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: line 1: {error:Not Found}: command not found
```

Comment: Funnily enough, for Windows & Mac everything is loaded and available while Linux users have to go through the drudgery of typing and installing stuff separately and figuring stuff out (which is fun of course)

Comment: This command worked for me on ubuntu/arm64 - sudo pip3 -v install docker-compose

Comment: use docker compose plugin instead

Answer (score 498, accepted):

You also need to install Docker Compose. See the [manual](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/). Here are the commands you need to execute

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.12.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"  -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

**Note:
Make sure that the link pointing to the GitHub release is not outdated!. [Check out the latest releases on GitHub](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases).**

Comment: When running the second line I receive a response: `mv: rename ./docker-compose to /usr/bin/docker-compose: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @kuanb if it says permission not permitted make sure u got full sudo rights

Comment: For now version 1.7.0 is old. According to https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/ new version is 1.11.2. It means that instead of curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.7.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > ./docker-compose should be used curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > ./docker-compose

Comment: Make sure that the link pointing to the GitHub release is not outdated! Check out the [latest releases on GitHub](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases). You can download the latest file from the browser too, then just move and give executable permission for it.

Comment: I got curious about what was in that docker-compose script and saw that it calls a python module entry point. So, docker-compose is a python module that gets installed with the engine, but the means to call it is only installed when you download the call script from github. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm still learning about docker, but as I understand docker-compose should not be used for new installs, as all its features have been integrated into the main docker-cli with `docker stack` and docker swarm. https://vsupalov.com/difference-docker-compose-and-docker-stack/ . Maybe this answer should mention that, as it appear first on google when looking for docker-compose

Comment: I just went ahead and ran `sudo apt install docker-compose` and didn't do anything else.

Comment: Github url format has changed. There should be a "v" in front of the version number. eg. .../download/v2.9.0/...

Answer (score 58):

I'm installing on a Raspberry Pi 3, with Raspbian 8. The curl method failed for me (got a `line 1: Not: command not found` error upon asking for `docker-compose --version`) and the solution of @sunapi386 seemed a little out-dated, so I tried this which worked:

First clean things up from previous efforts:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo pip uninstall docker-compose
```

Then follow [this guidance re docker-compose on Rpi](https://toub.es/2017/07/13/docker-raspberry-pi-perfect-combo/):

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-pip
sudo pip install docker-compose
```

For me (on 1 Nov 2017) this results in the following response to `docker-compose --version`:

```
docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac219
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly!

If you do not need the latest version of docker-compose, you can also use `apt-get install docker-compose`. Of course, this requires that you added the docker repository to your apt's sources.list (the install script from get.docker.com performs this automatically for you).

However, on my Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspian Stretch Lite this resulted in a really old version: `docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown`. This version is so old that it only supports version 2 of the docker-compose file format.

Comment: Awesome this helped me with getting docker-comps error on aws. Thanks

Comment: I had some troubles and used 'apt purge' and 'pip uninstall' for docker-compose and then reinstall again (not sure if one or both), but the important part of solution was also: pip install --upgrade docker-py

Comment: Perfect! without any curl, chmod and version checkings. Just automatic install last version. Should be acepted as answer.

Comment: Got a ton of errors when using pip to install docker-compose. If you do too, try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43012312/430773

Comment: It only worked for me after doing `pip3` instead of `pip`. Thank you though!

Answer (score 55):

If you installed docker by adding their official repository to your repository list, like:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-compose
```

In case on RHEL based distro / Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install docker-compose
```

Comment: Apt get --even after adding the repositories they specify for docker CE, seems to only contain `docker-compose` 1.8, which is compatible with a maximum `docker-compose.yml` file of version 2. In other words, they're no longer publishing `docker-compose` to `apt-get` default repositories or their own apt-get repository. In order to get newer versions it seems like you need to use `pip`. This annoys me, since its literally the only thing I'm using pip for.

Answer (score 31):

If you're using ubuntu and `docker compose` works but `docker-compose` doesn't, and you need the old `docker-compose` syntax to be available (maybe a 3rd party library uses it) you can fix it by following these steps:

the docker-compose plugin is probably installed under `/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose` (make sure it is)

create a symlink to it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Now `docker-compose` should be available

**Update:**

If `docker-compose` is no where to be found on the mentioned path, you can download it manually from [release page](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/) for your operating system and then move the downloaded file and make it executable.

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo mv ./docker-compose-* /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/docker-compose': No such file or directory
43612 /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
Do you have any idea?

Comment: @R.G.Krish It's probably because the docker-compose is not installed in the mentioned directory, maybe you can download it manually, I updated the answer

Comment: Yep, i have installed newly.  Using this. sudo apt-get install docker-compose

Comment: Great share!! This also works on centos

Answer (score 25):

**UPDATE May 2022**

Since April 2022 docker compose V2 is GA and it's now part of docker desktop. You can see all the related info [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/announcing-compose-v2-general-availability/).
Compose V1 is now marked as deprecated.

**Original answer:**

docker compose v1 is a separate install. To install v1 follow instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-20-04).

docker compose v2 is currently a separate install  but [will be integrated into docker at some point, when it's ready](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/). It has been conceived as a docker plugin. At this time, if you want docker compose v2, since [this](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce-packaging/pull/553) commit you can do:

```
sudo apt update \
&& sudo apt install docker-compose-plugin
```

with apt or the equivalent for yum. That will install the new docker compose V2 as a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was helpful. Just issuing `sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin` will install docker-compose cli plugin into `/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/`

Comment: And actually now `docker-compose` will trigger an error. Fun times with backwards-don'tcarebility

Comment: And do not forget to add the docker repository first

Answer (score 17):

I'm on debian, I found something quite natural to do :

```
apt-get install docker-compose
```

and it did the job
(not tested on centos)

Comment: This command will install version `1.25.0`. When you run `docker-compose --version`, the output will be `docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown`

Answer (score 17):

They changed the syntax. Now it is written like this:

```
docker compose [OPTIONS] COMMAND
docker compose ps
```

Now compose is plugin! But other doc pages have old syntax.
How I should support compatibility?!

UPDATE:
If you run script it can get compose command:

```bash
# docker-compose.sh
if docker compose version > /dev/null ; then
    echo "docker compose"
else
    echo "docker-compose"
fi

# other.sh
DOCKER_C=$($BASEDIR/docker-compose.sh)
echo "docker command is: $DOCKER_C"
```

Living on the crutches, thanks Docker command (:

Comment: Writing your own executable script named `docker-compose` which is a wrapper of the new syntax

Comment: Thank you!!! A solutions as simple as this ( they should create a warning for some time and then remove docker-compose)

Answer (score 11):

I'm installing on a Raspberry Pi 3, on Raspbian OS. The `curl` method didn't resolve to a valid response. It also said `{error: Not Found}`, I took a look at the URL `https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.2/docker-compose-Linux-armv7l` and it was not valid. I guess there was no build there.

This guide https://github.com/hypriot/arm-compose worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://packagecloud.io/Hypriot/Schatzkiste/debian/ jessie main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hypriot.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 37BBEE3F7AD95B3F
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-compose
```

Answer (score 9):

first of all please check if docker-compose is installed,

```
$ docker-compose -v
```

If it is not installed, please refer to the installation guide https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/
If installed give executable permission to the binary.

```
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

check if this works.

Answer (score 6):

Tried to install docker-compose on CentOS using `curl` per [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) (for Linux). After those steps it returned an error

```
docker-compose -v
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: line 1: Not: command not found
```

Funny thing `docker-compose` file literally contains just "Not Found" on line 1 (it should be a binary)

```
cat /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
Not Found
```

That means a github link I tried to curl from does not exist. My unsuccessful link was:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/2.2.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Running `uname -s` and `uname -m` locally you can see what needs to be added to a download url

```
uname -s
Linux
uname -m
x86_64
```

Trying the url in a browser
`https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/2.2.2/docker-compose-linux-x86_64` 
shows that page was not found.

A problem they added "v" to a version, as in `v2.2.2`. So a download url should be with "**v**"
`https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.2.2/docker-compose-linux-x86_64`. Their releases: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/

This worked (attention **v**2.2.2)

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.2.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose -v
Docker Compose version v2.2.2
```

Comment: So a download url should be with "v".... thanks bro...

Answer (score 3):

Refered to the answers given above (I do not have enough reputation to refer separately to individual solutions, hence I do this collectively in this place), I want to supplement them with some important suggestions:

1. docker-compose you can install from the repository (if you have this package in the repository, if not you can adding to system a repository with this package) or download binary with use curl - totourial on the official website of the project - src: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install /
2. docker-compose from the repository is in version 1.8.0 (at least at me). This docker-compose version does not support configuration files in version 3. It only has version = <2 support. Inthe official site of the project is a recommendation to use container configuration in version 3 - src: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file / compose-versioning /. From my own experience with work in the docker I recommend using container configurations in version 3 - there are more configuration options to use than in versions <3. If you want to use the configurations configurations in version 3 you have to do update / install docker-compose to the version of at least 1.17 - preferably the latest stable. The official site of the project is toturial how to do this process - src: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/
3. when you try to manually remove the old docker-compose binaries, you can have information about the missing file in the default path `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose`. At my case, docker-compose was in the default path /usr/bin/docker-compose. In this case, I suggest you use the find tool in your system to find binary file docker-compose - example syntax: `sudo find / -name 'docker-compose'`. It helped me. Thanks to this, I removed the old docker-compose version and added the stable to the system - I use the curl tool to download binary file docker-compose, putting it in the right path and giving it the right permissions - all this process has been described in the posts above.

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 3):

just use brew:

```
brew install docker-compose
```

Comment: It's a Linux question.  While brew exists for Linux it's not commonly used.

Answer (score 3):

its as simple as noting that earlier version of docker engine below 2 uses `docker-compose` (with the dash) commands while docker engine of version 2 uses `docker compose` (Without the dash). Hence you have to uninstall your old version to get a newer and work with `docker compose` command rather than `docker-compose`.

Verify with following command via terminal to see your current version

```
docker compose version
**or**
docker-compose version
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of suggestions for Ubuntu OS, but imho the easiest solution is to just create an alias. (if docker compose is already installed)

Steps:

- `ls -la` inside your `~` directory to see if there is a `.bash_aliases`
- if not just create it (`touch`, `nano`... or simply with `gedit`) `gedit .bash_aliases`
- (the above steps can be skipped and just add your aliases inside `.bashrc`)
- add the alias `alias docker-compose="docker compose"`
- make the aliases available in your current session: `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

Installing docker doesn't mean that you've installed docker-compose. It has as prerequisitions that you've already installed the docker engine which you've already done. After that you're able to install docker-compose following this [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) for Centos 7.

Comment: No, i did run that command " yum install docker-engine " but i get error
Package docker-engine-1.11.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version and still no docker-compose it gives me error

/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: line 1: {error:Not Found}: command not found

Comment: Like I said: Docker engine is something different than Docker compose. So you can installl the docker engine and just work with docker but when you want to use docker compose you need to install it seperatly (where the installation of the engine is a prerequisition (you've alread done this)). So try now the link I gave in the answer (you can use curl or pip to install docker-compose)

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions didn't work for me. But I found this that worked:

```
sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh
sudo pip3 install docker-compose
#sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-profess.yml pull ofw
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

For installing Docker Compose v1, you can install as following:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose --version
```

For installing Docker Compose v2, you can refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

For command compatibility between the new compose and the old docker-compose, you can refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command-compatibility/).

Answer (score 1):

From the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/#install-docker-compose):

> If you installed Docker Desktop/Toolbox for either Windows or Mac, you
> already have Docker Compose! Play-with-Docker instances already have
> Docker Compose installed as well. If you are **on a Linux machine, you
> will need to [install Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)**.

For that, you need to refer to the [Pre-existing Docker Installation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#pre-existing-docker-installation) section.

Answer (score 1):

first things first: sometimes the "docker-compose-plugin" could not be found" error is due to the fact that you are trying to "invoke" it from the WSL distro and you have not started docker-desktop on windows.

If you don't find it, you can install it as directed by other users. Warning: very often when you run a "`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin`" you may get an error because Ubuntu cannot find the repositories therefore, you need to add (official guide https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository):

```
# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
```

after this, you can run "`apt-get install docker-compose-plugin`"

Answer (score 1):

For me, `Docker compose` was installed along with `Docker Desktop`

Try -

```
docker compose
```

In place of `docker-compose` and it should work!

For example -

```
docker compose version
```

Comment: Also, I have added an `alias` in my shell to make it easier for me.  
`alias docker-compose="docker compose"`
(not sure if it does any harm? For now, it's working for me)

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose is currently a tool that utilizes docker(-engine) but is not included in the distribution of docker.

Here is the link to the installation manual:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

TL;DR:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.8.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

(1.8.0 will change in the future)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the official pkg on Mac.  I guess docker-compose is no longer included with docker by default:  https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_mac/

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can download the Docker Compose binary from the Compose repository release page on GitHub. Follow the instructions from the link, which involve running the curl command in your terminal to download the binaries. These step-by-step instructions are also included below.

1:Run this command to download the current stable release of Docker Compose:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

To install a different version of Compose, substitute 1.26.2 with the version of Compose you want to use.

2:Apply executable permissions to the binary:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

> Note: If the command docker-compose fails after installation, check
> your path. You can also create a symbolic link to /usr/bin or any
> other directory in your path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to auto install docker-compose latest version, just run:

```
export docker_compose_latest=$(curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective}  https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest  | grep -o '[^/]*$')
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${docker_compose_latest}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

It will install latest version of docker-compose. [Official installing way](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) need version obtained by your hands. But I wrote a script which obtain the latest version for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Had a few issues with CentOS Stream, and here's the script I created to re-use (just change the version variable as you please):

##### Centos

```bash
# Ref: Installing docker-compose (ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-centos-7)
# Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685980/why-is-docker-installed-but-not-docker-compose

docker_compose_version=2.22.0;
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/docker-compose;
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v${docker_compose_version}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"  -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose;
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose;
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose;
which docker-compose;
ls -lh `which docker-compose`;

# Ref: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5337
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir docker-compose && ln -sf /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

##### Alpine

Ensure community repo is enabled in /etc/apk/repositories

```bash
apk update
apk add docker
rc-update add docker boot
service docker start

apk add curl;
rm -f /usr/bin/docker-compose;
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v${docker_compose_version}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"  -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose;
mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose;

chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose;
which docker-compose;
ls -lh `which docker-compose`;
```

I left the original sources of documentation as comments, so that you know where this idea came from.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS and Docker Desktop installation you don't need to install Docker Compose separately. But you might need to add Docker path to your PATH. Try adding the below line to either of these files:  `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.docker/bin
```

More on this in the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/mac/#advanced-1).

Comment: This is not directly related to the OP's question, but I had the same `docker-compose command not found` error. So, what worked for me would probably help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

If docker-compose is already persists in **/usr/local/bin**:

```
ls -alt /usr/local/bin/ | grep docker-compose
> lrwxr-xr-x    1 root     wheel        77 Mar 11 10:39 docker-compose -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-compose/docker-compose
```

Then update your .bash_profile Path with this `/usr/local/bin` in the end:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

Run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And check:

```
echo $PATH
> ...
which docker-compose
> /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose
```