# how to install docker-compose for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using gitlab-runner to install docker-compose. Any solution to my query.

[gitlab-ci.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4xxg.png)

[build-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEQGX.png)

Are there more steps that I have to follow?

ex. [Docker is installed but Docker Compose is not ? why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685980/docker-is-installed-but-docker-compose-is-not-why)

Comment: Have you tried this [https://gist.github.com/wesleybliss/29d4cce863f5964a3eb73c42501d99e4](https://gist.github.com/wesleybliss/29d4cce863f5964a3eb73c42501d99e4)

Comment: @Valijon ; yes. docker-compose.yaml is already there in my proj. structure

Comment: Perhaps you can try using the `compose:1.23.2` image directly?

Comment: It worked, Thank you